# Specify the superscript for each author in a R bookdown file

Tags: r, r-markdown, bookdown

Is it possible to specify the character next to the author's names in a `bookdown` file?

Consider this `.Rmd` file:

```
---
title: "Untitled"
author:
- Author1^[Info about Author1]
- Author2^[Info about Author2]
output:
  bookdown::pdf_book
---
```

Next to the authors we see the superscripts `*` and the other special character (sorry, I cannot find how to show it). I would like to change to `a` and `b` for example.